# Comparing 2 files and return the different with label

Tags: python

I want to compare 2 file line by line and return me the differences along with the label before and after the differences.

File1.txt:

```
    Books:
     {A}-children
     {A}-Parents
     {A}-Gramps
    Volume:
     {A}-300
     {A}-400
```

File2.txt:

```
    Books:
     {A}-childrenA
     {A}-Parents
     {A}-Gramps
    Volume:
     {A}-300
     {A}-400
```

The output that i am expecting would be:

```
    Books:
    {A}-Children
    Volume:
```

this is my code so far:

```py
    with open(file1, 'r') as f:
        f1_line = set(f.readlines())
    
    
    with open(file2, 'r') as f:
        f2_line = set(f.readlines())
    
    for line in list(f1_line - f2_line):
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could append each line to an array and then compare the contents easily like so.

```
file_contents1 = []
file_contents2 = []
differences = []

with open('./file1.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        file_contents1.append(line)

with open('./file2.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        file_contents2.append(line)


for i in file_contents1:
    if not i in file_contents2:
        differences.append(i)
```

#differences list now contains all different elements